# Nginx static files not being served

Tags: nginx

I am trying to run a Laravel install (a php application) when a user accesses a subdirectory of my server. I am using Nginx to serve both this and the main site (Wordpress).

The directory structure is as follows:

```
/app
  /shop        - Laravel
  /public      - Wordpress
```

[I have my full site.conf file here](https://pastebin.com/Jpg6mmsF)

In it, I have a laravel.conf which looks like this:

```
location /shop {


    alias /app/shop/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @shop;

    autoindex on;


    location ~ \.php$ {

        try_files $uri =404;

        include /etc/nginx/includes/fastcgi_params.conf;
        fastcgi_index           index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info     ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO   $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;

        fastcgi_pass            unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info     ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
    }

}

location @shop{
    rewrite /shop/(.*)$ /shop/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

If I go to `mysite.dev/` it loads the Wordpress site with all css and js assets, and if I go to `mysite.dev/shop` it loads the Laravel site. But it doesn't load any of the css files found in `/app/shop/public/css/app.css` (404 error).

I switched on `autoindex` and if I navigate to `mysite.dev/shop/css` it shows `app.css`.

What do I need to add to serve the static files?

Is the `try_files` block wrong?

I have been trying to work out if its [something in the rest of the config](https://pastebin.com/Jpg6mmsF) that is catching requests for css and js files and routing them back through the regular public folder?

Comment: You get a 404 on the URL path `/app/shop/public/css/app.css`? OK then check what is on the filesystem at `/app/shop/public/public/css/app.css`. My guess is that the file isn't there.

Comment: Hi @MichaelHampton  it is there as proved by removing `app.css` from the url. The folder is correctly autoindexed with `app.css` in the folder. Also looking in the directory shows the same. Thanks

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to why you wanted the `public` in the directory structure twice.

Comment: Does it serve the the static files if you comment out the `try_files` statement?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the line

`alias /app/shop/public;`

should be

`alias /app/shop;`

In that way you shouldn't need the last location block.